# missing data in table with php

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

Currently I am calling a table of publications and add a page with php, when going through the data with a foreach, I have noticed that I am missing 3 data, for example it brings me the ID 1 but hey it jumps to ID 5 without showing the ID's [ 2,3,4]

[image]

In the previous image it is shown what I commented previously, it does not show all the fields of the table.

the data model i am using is the following:

```html
    public function list( $uuid = null, $usuario_uuid = null, $estado_id = null, $pagina = 0)
    {
        $this->db->select('publicacion.*,
            concat(usuario.nombre, " ", usuario.paterno) as "usuario",
            COALESCE(renta.nombre, "No definido") as "renta",
            COALESCE(jornada.nombre, "No definido") as "jornada",
            COALESCE(comuna.nombre, "No definido") as "comuna",
            COALESCE(profesion.nombre, "No definido") as "profesion",
            rango_etario.desde, rango_etario.hasta,
            renta.desde as renta_desde, renta.hasta as renta_hasta,
            ');
        $this->db->join('usuario', 'usuario.uuid = publicacion.usuario_uuid');
        $this->db->join('renta', 'renta.id = publicacion.renta_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('jornada', 'jornada.id = publicacion.jornada_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('comuna', 'comuna.id = publicacion.comuna_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('profesion', 'profesion.id = publicacion.profesion_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('rango_etario', 'rango_etario.id = publicacion.rango_etario_id', 'left');

        if ($uuid != null) {
            $this->db->where('publicacion.uuid', $uuid);
            return $this->db->get('publicacion',REGISTROS_PAGINA, $pagina)->row_array();
        }
        if ($usuario_uuid != null) {
            $this->db->where('publicacion.usuario_uuid', $usuario_uuid);
        }
        if ($estado_id != null) {
            $this->db->where('publicacion.estado_publicacion_id', $estado_id);
        }
        return $this->db->get('publicacion')->result_array();
    }
  
  
    function total($usuario_uuid = null, $estado = null)
    {
        if ($usuario_uuid != null) {
            $this->db->where('publicacion.usuario_uuid', $usuario_uuid);
        }
        if ($estado != null) {
            $this->db->where('publicacion.estado_publicacion_id', $estado);
        }else{
            $this->db->where_in('publicacion.estado_publicacion_id', [1,2]);
        }
        return $this->db->get('publicacion')->num_rows();
    }
```

my controller is the following:

```html
function publicaciones($offset = 0)
    {
        $this->load->model('Modelo_publicacion');
        $this->load->model('Modelo_usuario');
        
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url("Administracion/publicaciones");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Modelo_publicacion->total();
        $config['per_page'] = REGISTROS_PAGINA;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['num_links'] = 5;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['attributes'] = ['class' => 'page-link'];
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data["paginacion"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        
        $data["publicaciones"] = $this->Modelo_publicacion->list(null, null, null, $offset);
        $this->load->view('admin/publicaciones/list_publicaciones', $data);
    }
```

and finally my html code section from where I call the data:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 offset-1 table-responsive pt-3">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
            <thead class="thead-dark bg-secondary">
                 <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Tipo Empleo</th>
                <th>Comuna</th>
                <th>Jornada</th>
                <th>Renta ofrecida</th>
                <th>Fecha publicación</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php sort($publicaciones);
                        foreach ($publicaciones as $p) { ?>
                            <tr>
                             <td><?= $p["id"] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $p["usuario"] ?></td>
                            <?php if($p["nombre"] != null){ ?>
                            <td><?= $p["nombre"] ?></td>
                            <?php } else { ?>  
                            <td>No definido</td>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <td><?= $p["comuna"] ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $p["jornada"] ?> </td>
                        <td><?= $p["renta_id"] == "-1" ? $p["otra_remuneracion"] : $p["renta"] ?></td>
                        <td> <?= $p["fecha_creacion"] ?> </td>
                        <td> <?= $p["estado_publicacion_id"] ?> </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

I've changed the model and controller data, but I'm still missing data. Also look for similar questions but none have an answer that has helped me solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe this condition need to be 'left' like the other ? $this->db->join('usuario', 'usuario.uuid = publicacion.usuario_uuid');

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with HTML or AJAX. The problem is just that your query isn't returning those rows.

Comment: Use `var_dump($publicaciones)` to see the data returned by the query.